# How can this function in Haskell be optimised

Tags: performance, haskell

As part of an advent of code challenge, I've written the following functions in Haskell:

```
simulateUntilRepeat_int a b i = if (a /= b) then (simulateUntilRepeat_int a (updateCycle b) (i+1)) else i

simulateUntilRepeat a = simulateUntilRepeat_int a (updateCycle a) 1
```

The purpose of this is to take a list of moons and simulate their movement until they resume their original position, returning the number of cycles it took for them to get there. (the function updateCycle does one iteration of the simulation). However, when I attempt to run this it uses all available memory and then gets killed by the operating system. The question does admit that this may take a very large number of cycles.

Googling around about this problem I find the usual fix is to make some of the parameters strict, but I think I've experimented with all possible permutations of strictness on the parameters to no avail. By the looks of this function, I'd have anticipated the compiler would be able to use the tail recursion optimisation and turn it into a loop, but this seems to not be happening somehow.

A friend of mine, who is knowledgeable in haskell suggested changing the form of the function to the following:

```
f a b0 = length (takeWhile (/= a) (iterate updateCycle b0))
```

But doing this didn't fix it either, leaving me out of ideas.

Comment: I'm also doing this year's Advent of Code in Haskell - but I fear you've missed the point of this problem. I'm not sure if or how you can fix it to run in constant memory (I'm no expert in such things), but even if you can, the runtime will be totally unreasonable. You need to break the problem down into smaller chunks in order to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not sure - it states the example would take 4,686,774,924 iterations which is significant, but not intractable. I suspect a C++ implementation could do this in a minute or two.

Comment: Well I'd be surprised if any language could do this significantly faster than a million iterations per second, at which rate that would still take about an hour and a quarter. (You might be prepared to wait that long, but the FAQ explicitly says no solution should take more than 15 seconds to run with the right algorithm.) And my answer was several orders of magnitude greater than that number. (I say "my answer" because I think AoC gives slightly different inputs to different users, but I'd expect they're all of a similar size.)

Comment: Ok. Well, I'll think about another solution, but I'm still interested in how the memory problem with this implementation might be solved, in case I run into this issue again.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Your thought is correct.

Comment: Yes. I was able to rewrite it to take about 10 seconds to complete, so Robin Zigmond was right about that one. I also marked K.A.Buhr's answer correct, as he pointed out that the speed problem doesn't seem to be in the section of code I posted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are undoubtedly correct that your approach is not the intended solution method.

However, the functions you've posted would not, in and of themselves, cause a memory leak, fail to tail recurse, or lead to poor performance.  Given your code above plus the definitions:

```
updateCycle 4686774942 = 0
updateCycle n = n+1

main = do
  print $ simulateUntilRepeat (0 :: Int)
```

and compiling with `-O2`, the program runs in constant memory on my laptop in about 30 seconds.  Adding explicit type signatures to use `Int` in place of `Integer` for the iteration count:

```
simulateUntilRepeat_int :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
simulateUntilRepeat :: Int -> Int
```

it runs in about 2.4 seconds.

So, to understand why your program is gobbling all available memory or why your strictness annotations failed to make a difference, it would probably be necessary to see the whole working program (or preferably a minimal example that illustrates the performance problem).  If the program is short, and the question is "why is the performance of this program totally unreasonable?" instead of "how can I optimize my program to run as fast as possible?", it might still be a good SO question.  Otherwise, the Code Review site might be better -- you can post a larger program there and ask for general performance advice, and that's considered on-topic for that site.